# How to scale the values in a column based on values in other column in google spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I want to scale the value of column A and write it in column C based on it's corresponding value in column B and scaling values are given in column F.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318).

In C:

```
=$A1*VLOOKUP($B1, $E$1:$F$3, 2, FALSE)
```

To do all the lines in a single formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA($A1:A*VLOOKUP($B1:B, $E$1:$F$3, 2, FALSE))
```

Comment: Thank it works, but at the end of the columns where there is no data in column A and B, I am getting error in the corresponding C column, see the image in the question.

Comment: and I don't want to restrict the number of values in columns  A and B  from 1 to 15, because values are added to these columns from time to time.

Comment: Add an IFERROR after ARRAYFORMULA.